# Electron App Installation to ProgramFiles

Tags: electron, electron-builder

What's the best way to make an electron app installer so that it installs it in ProgramFiles? I am using the electron-builder, but it installs the app in %appdata%

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The installer will indeed install in %appdata% if you have set build/nsis/perMachine to false (which is default) in your package.json. If you set perMachine to true, the program will be installed in program files, and furthermore if you set oneClick to false, you allow the user to choose where to install.

Comment: but is there any way to set the app installation path as per our choice and set oneClick to true?